# Select all combinations of some rows with other rows so that one column is eliminated

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

| word1 | Word 2 | Number 1 | Number 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 | 2 |
| A | B | 1 | 3 |
| A | B | 1 | 4 |
| A | B | 5 | 6 |
| A | B | 5 | 9 |

What I want is to transform these 4 columns in 3 columns with all the combinations of column1,column2,number(1+2)

Output:

| word1 | Word 2 | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 |
| A | B | 2 |
| A | B | 3 |
| A | B | 4 |
| A | B | 5 |
| A | B | 6 |
| A | B | 9 |

Comment: Common UNION DISTINCT.

Comment: With what table? Do you mean making UNION DISTINCT with a join of the same table itself?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT word1, word2, number1 AS number FROM source_table
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT word1, word2, number2 FROM source_table
```

Comment: `UNION` only returns unique rows in all databases: deleting the optional `DISTINCT` keyword makes no difference to the result, but makes the answer portable (only MySQL supports that syntax).